# Remove an item from local storage in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

#### Is this the right code to remove an item from *localStorage*:

```
onDelete(name) {
        console.log("ProductList.onDelete: ", name);
        let {products} = this.state;
        products = products.filter(product => product.name !== name);
        this.setState({products});
        localStorage.setItem('products', JSON.stringify(products));
}
```

Comment: localStorage.removeItem(); is used then how to get the exact item to be removed.

Answer (score 11):

To remove items from your local storage, you simply have to run:

```
localStorage.removeItem("name of the item")
```

Comment: onDelete(name) {
        console.log("ProductList.onDelete: ", name);
        let {products} = this.state;
        products = products.filter(product => product.name !== name);
        this.setState({products});
        localStorage.removeItem('products', JSON.stringify(products));
    }

Comment: Yes, but i think if you need to remove an item from an array that you have to put in some key value as well or split the array.

Comment: products.filter(product => product.name !== name);   is this line finding  the item by name

Comment: You don't really use localStorage for arrays. Check out the map function in react if you really want to do things like this. You don't have any 'id' with localStorage, you can simply delete things via calling the exact name of the localStorage Item. If you have an item called (hello), well it will be deleted. But if you have 10 Items that are called "hello", all 10 of them will be deleted via localStorage.removeItem, simply because you don't have any id's attached to them. Your products need to be an array in order to do this. Again, check out the map function of react.

Answer (score 4):

```
    let items =JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("item"));
    items = items.filter((item) => item.id !== id);
    localStorage.setItem("item", JSON.stringify(items));
    if (items.length === 0) {
      localStorage.removeItem("item");
    }
```

Comment: Provide explanation

Answer (score 1):

@Prometheus is correct.

Since, you have asked for ReactJS, I hope that following fiddle helps you:
https://jsfiddle.net/ghoshnirmalya/eqb9vych/5/.

```
addItem = () => localStorage.setItem("name", this.state.name)

removeItem = () => localStorage.removeItem("name")
```

I have added a whole example in ReactJS.